# How to access parent object from lambda functions?

Tags: php, class, function, lambda, closures

I have a recursive lambda function in one of my objects, and it needs to access the object's mysqli connection. This attempt

```
$recfunc = function($id, $name) use($this) {
```

Produced an unreasonable fatal error

> Fatal error: Cannot use $this as lexical variable in C:\Users\Codemonkey1991\Desktop\workspace\melior\objects\databasemanager.php on line 88

Could anyone give me a few pointers?

---

Edit: Just to clarify context, I'm trying to create this lambda function inside another function.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Because closures are themselves objects, you need to assign `$this` to a local variable, like:

```
$host = $this;
$recfunc = function($id, $name) use ($host) { ...
```

Comment: Hey, just an additional question: How would I go about getting the function to call itself?

Comment: `$recfunc = function($id, $name) use ($host, &$recfunc) { if (FOO) return $recfunc($id, $name); }`

Comment: From checking a bugs.php.net report on this error, this feature has been added to PHP 5.4.

Answer (score 5):

The reference to `$this` does not need to be explicitly passed to the lambda function.

```
class Foo {
    public $var = '';

    public function bar() {
        $func = function() {
            echo $this->var;
        };
        $func();
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->var = 'It works!';
$foo->bar(); // will echo 'It works!'
```